# codeigniter 2 pagination doesn't work with _remap

Tags: php, view, pagination, codeigniter-2

Paginator is loading 404 page for pages from second. Gues problem is in _remap method existing in this controller.

My paginator:

```
   $this->config->load('pagination', TRUE);
    $config = array_merge($this->config->item('pagination'), Array(
        'base_url'   => site_url() . "/welcome",
        'total_rows'  => count($commentsOfInterview),
        'per_page'   => 2,
        'uri_segment'  => 2,
    ));
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(1)) ? $this->uri->segment(1) : 1;
    $commentsList['comments'] = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Comment')->findPageOfActive($page, $config["per_page"], 'DESC', $lastInterviewId);
    $commentsList['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Paginator is loading but for pages from 2 it loads 404 page. How can i solve this problem not removing _remap?

Comment: Show your _remap content.

Comment: I added my _remap. I try check if page exists i _remap, because when i use _remap, CI stops checking it himself

Comment: I'd like to add one more if to my _remap which will check if segment(2) is numeric, and passes back control to the method, but so that the second page of paginator will be loaded. How to implement this?

Comment: Maybe you can add $this->page = ($this->uri->segment(1)) ? $this->uri->segment(1) : 1; in _remap

Comment: pls edit my _remap with this line. I can't understand what do u mean

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function _remap($method) {
        if(method_exists($this, $method)){
            if( $this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->getUserId() === null && $this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->getUserRole() !== 'VISITOR'){
                $this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->setUserRole('VISITOR');
                $options=array(
                    'client_id' => 'interview',
                    'client_secret' => 'interview',

                );
                $params=array(
                    'scope'=>'email',
                    'cur_uri' => 'http://192.168.0.129/index.php/' . $this->uri->uri_string(),
                    'redirect_uri' => 'http://192.168.0.129/index.php/UserController/authorise/muloqot',  //?connect=muloqot',

                );
                $client = new Oauth2_MuloqotClientAPI($options);
                $client->isAuthorized($params);
            }
/*            else if($this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->getUserRole() === 'VISITOR'){
                $this->em->getRepository('Entities\User')->deleteSessionData();
            }*/
            if ($this->uri->segment(3)) {
                return $this->$method($this->uri->segment(3));
            } else return $this->$method();
        } else {
            $error404 = site_url($this->router->routes['404_override']);
            redirect($error404);
        }
    }
```